# Modx Revolution tree of resources (documents)

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have a trouble with resources tree (left side of admin panel)
If I open some item for editing, tree is closing and I need open tree every time. It is observes this problem on some computer (not in all) and not every time (sometime tree does not collapse). Where does find it solve of this problem. What does it relate problem with?
You can see [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQXR6CvmSuyVGozZVlqcElqWlk/view?usp=sharing) for understanding.

Comment: Do you have multiple tabs open? The states are saved in the session state in the database. This is overwritten on interaction and cancels the old actions.

Comment: Problem was resolve by creating new administrator. At new user this trouble does not seen. Old user was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

if this was my website, I would try and:

- delete the cookie for this site
- reinstall MODX (just rerun the setup)